# Countable Infinite and Uncountable Infinite sets

Tags: infinite-groups

Mark each statement as TRUE, FALSE, or UNKNOWN

(a) $|\Bbb{R}| < \aleph_1$

(b) $|\Bbb{R}| = \aleph_1$

(c) $|P(\Bbb{R})| > \aleph_1$

Could someone explain to me the reasoning based on whatever the answer is for each one because I do not fully understand Countable Infinite and Uncountable Infinite sets

Comment: Then read up on countable infinite vs. uncountable infinite.  There is *nothing* we can say that can't be said better in a good text.

Comment: @fleablood have read about it and even watched youtube clips, but still don't know how to answer the questions given.

Comment: Then it's up to you to ask us a question we can answer for you.  We can't read your mind and know *why* you don't understand it.

Answer (score 0):

$\aleph_1$ by definition is the *first* uncountable cardinal number.
So $|A| < \aleph_1$ by definition means that $A$ is a countable set.
The reals are not countable.

We (should) know that $|\mathbb{R}| = |P(\mathbb{N})| = 2^{\aleph_0}> \aleph_0$. So in particular $2^{\aleph_0} \ge \aleph_1$. 
The so-called [continuum hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis) (which is independent of ZFC, so "unknown" in your list) states that $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_1$.

By Cantor's theorem $|P(\mathbb{R})| = 2^{|\mathbb{R}|}= 2^{2^{\aleph_0}} > 2^{\aleph_0} \ge \aleph_1$.